# Where is MopaBootstrap defined in symfony?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I use MopaBootstrap in the twig and other places, but I want to know where it is defined.

```
{% extends "@MopaBootstrap/layout.html.twig" %}
{% from '@MopaBootstrap/flash.html.twig' import session_flash %}

{% block headline %}Choice Widgets{% endblock headline %}

{% block content %}
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <form action="#" class="form-horizontal" method="post" >

        {{ form_widget(form) }}

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <h3>Choice form widgets</h3>
    <p>Here we try to show all possible choice form widgets</p>
    <hr>
    <p>And there is a lot to do</p>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: {% extends "@MopaBootstrap/layout.html.twig" %} ,the "@MopaBootstrap ..."

Comment: It should be in your vendor directory if you installed it via composer. `vendor/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/views/`